# Flutter animations, Flare VS GIF

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flare, rive

I found that we can make amazing animations with Flare. but can't we do the same with using gifs files?

What's the difference between Flare animations and using gif files in a Flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

I dont use rive but I think the answer is in the possibilities.
That is

> dynamic, interactive, & animated experiences , with gif it would be possible but it would be a bit hectic , like handling which gif to show when something happens would be problematic .
> Suppose you have two animation A and B , what if you want to mix it ? and do A and B together , then you would probably have to make another seperate gif for that. But for rive you mix the two animations with a few lines of code ( [check this page](https://blog.rive.app/rives-flutter-runtime-part-1/) for an example )
> And not to say , rive has vector graphics ( meaning you can infinitely zoom without loss of resolution) , whereas gif is raster graphics ( meaning you cannot infinitely zoom ) .

The advantages that rive has is mostly for complex animations.